# same css styling renders different positions on same ad

Tags: css, css-float

Ads on this page ([Fixture Info](http://oursportsplace.com/groups/afl-sample/?page=fixture_info)) are not displayed at same position as this ([Home Page](http://oursportsplace.com/groups/afl-sample/)). Both have the ads placed in `<div class="right-ad">`, and use the same style rules.

Any idea how to fix this & display ads on [Fixture Info](http://oursportsplace.com/groups/afl-sample/?page=fixture_info) in same position as [Home Page](http://oursportsplace.com/groups/afl-sample/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add more detail in your question and not really expect people to go to your site and analyse your code.

Never-the-less..

Check your code and you will notice that on your [Home Page](http://oursportsplace.com/groups/afl-sample/) the `<div class="right-ad">`'s parent is `<div class="main">`. Whereas on [Fixture Info](http://oursportsplace.com/groups/afl-sample/?page=fixture_info) the `<div class="right-ad">`'s parent is `<div class="container">`.

I would assume that this is the cause of your problem. Go over your code and you'll probably find that on the [Fixture Info](http://oursportsplace.com/groups/afl-sample/?page=fixture_info) page, putting the ad's `<div>` in the `<div class="main">` will solve it.

**I.E:**

Your **Home Page**:

[image]

Your **Fixtures Page**:

[image]